# How Do You Compare a Range of Float Decimal Numbers in xCode?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

This code does not work. Any suggestions?

```
float tempNum = 0.590000;
int temporary;
if (tempNum >= 0.590000 && tempNum <= 0.610000){
    temporary = 15;
}
// temporary yields zero
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So:

By default 0.590000 is a **DOUBLE**

So `float tempNum = 0.59000` causes a cast.

To prove this try:

```
float tempNum = 0.590000f;
int temporary;
if (tempNum >= 0.590000f && tempNum <= 0.610000f){
    temporary = 15;
}
```

So, remember that:

*aaa.aaa* is a **DOUBLE**

*aaa.aaaf* is **FLOAT**